# How to use a FractionallySizedBox inside a Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a `FractionallySizedBox` inside a `Column` to make my app responsive, but I get

> Needs Layout Error.

How can I use a `FractionallySizedBox` inside a `Column`?

Comment: You should report this as a bug, it should be able to function inside a Row or Column.

Comment: How is that a bug? Rows and Columns are unbounded, meaning they have no fraction. If you want to do a fraction of a Row or column then you could use the Flexible widgets and set their flex properties accordingly. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LayoutBuilder` instead.

Comment: LayoutBuilder instead of FractionallySizedBox? How would you use it with percentage?

Comment: LayoutBuilder gives you the size of the largest bounds. Once you have the dimensions you could size everything within the layoutbuilder based off of the dimensions you receive from the BoxConstraints argument in the actual builder. With max height you can calculate whatever you need. Other options are using Rect or RelativeRects, or for some of the most control you could use the CustomMultiChildLayout widget, which the delegate you have to create has options for layout arrangement. Or to use a column/row use the Flexible widget and don't make the flex property null. Any of those would suffice.